# Writing to file and reading from file when no internet

Tags: java, android

How to write the data from Web API to a file and  how to read data from that file if no internet?

```
public static boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context _context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You need at least once your app run over internet, And than save your file in NSUserDefault, So that you can access it as offline mode.

Comment: I suggest you do not write it to the `NSUserDefault` but just to a file in the document directory. The `NSUserDefault` is not ment to hold large chucks of data but just small settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not request a web service in offline mode. What is the best you can do is, you can apply client cash(setting max-age, s-maxage , max-stale in request header) or simply save the data from your web api in a local database like sqlite or Realm.